# Check 21, Image Cash Letter with C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a Check 21/Image Cash Letter(X9.37- 2003) for a .Net C# project I am working on and I am having a terrible time doing it.  Does anyone know where I can get some sample code or a library or something for this?  This seems to be a very popular way for banks to send scanned checks so it seems like there should be a lot of information out there for it.

I have looked at X9.org but they don't seems to have what I need.  I have a specification document that tells me what the file needs to look like but their appears to be some sort of encoding on top of that that is causing me problems.

Anything to help with this would be very helpful especially code examples or libraries.  Thank you.

Comment: According to [www.x937.com](http://www.x937.com/), the text is EBCDIC.

Comment: Thank you but do you have any idea which one?  I tried the different EBCDIC encodings I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding.aspx but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: No, I just googled to find that link.  Maybe you can post another question with some code and a more specific description of what isn't working.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

There's not a lot of decent sample code floating around the web for working with x9 files (especially so for writing a well formed x9 file).

In order to write a valid x9.37 (or x9.100-187) file, you're going to have to have a very comprehensive understanding of the ANSI spec(s). There's not much of a way around that. The spec is very specific about what constitutes a valid x9 file, why it would be accepted or rejected by receiving institutions, etc. There are a lot of rules that pertain to record placement in relation to other records and image formatting in particular.

Also, your confusion about the encoding of the file is not surprising as it's a bit complicated. X9.37 (& .100-187) files are binary files. **Most** of the data in the file is **usually** EBCDIC encoded string data, however you'll also come across some that are ASCII encoded. You can get at the EBCDIC encoding like: `Encoding.GetEncoding(37)`

Another aspect is that all records in the file are theoretically variable length and so are prefixed with their length in bytes. The strange thing about that is the length is stored as a big-endian, binary 32-bit integer. Lastly, the image data carried within is, of course, binary data.

I've created a nice, comprehensive .net library for working with x9 files, but for now it's only available for use by our company's products. We are toying with the idea of releasing a commercial SDK for .NET developers, given sufficient demand.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on this the last couple of weeks, as I have been tasked to make files for doing RDC to Wells Fargo. Unfortunately for me, while Wells Fargo people know the structure of the file very well, they don't understand encoding or binary data. I've spent the past 2 days parsing a sample file from them, and here's what I've discovered:

1. There are no line termination characters, such as \r\n. Each line, except for the 52 record, is 80 characters long, and must be parsed/created as such. Putting in line break characters will make an 81st and potentially 82nd character that will screw up the parser.
2. While the encoding of the file is EBCDIC (Encoding.GetEncoding(37)), the entire file IS NOT EBCDIC encoded. Only the text portions are encoded. So, you must encode to EBCDIC character by character up to the point where you are putting binary image data in the 52 record. At that point you simply put the binary data, and any parser should know the length of that data based on the previous field (field 18, length of image data, usually positions 111-117 of 52 record)

This is a very old question, but I've run across this one numerous times while researching my setup, so I figured it was time to give a proper answer with real information.

Comment: "the entire file IS NOT EBCDIC encoded. Only the ASCII portions are encoded." I understand what you are trying to say, but technically speaking, this makes no sense :) ASCII and EBCDIC are alternatives to each other for encoding text as bytes. But you are right: The entire file is not EBCDIC encoded. And that's simply because the entire file is not a text file.